# Overlap Paths in Canvas Android

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view, porter-duff

I am trying to draw a shape which is made of a number of paths:-

multiple ***Grey*** line path like this one

```
Path path1 = new Path();
    path1.moveTo(2 * w, 2 * h);
    path1.lineTo(0, 2 * h - perpendicular);
    pathColorList.add(Pair.create(path1, Color.GRAY));
```

and ***Blue*** line path like this one

```
    Path path2 = new Path();
    path2.moveTo(0, 2 * h - perpendicular);
    path2.lineTo(w * 2, 2 * h - 2 * perpendicular);
    pathColorList.add(Pair.create(path2, Color.BLUE));
```

`pathColorList`  is list of paths and their paint colors.

```
List<Pair<Path, Integer>> pathColorList = new ArrayList<Pair<Path, Integer>>();
```

- The Problem is I need ***Blue*** path always on top of ***Grey*** path. Even if  ***Grey*** path overlap ***Blue*** path; Overlap region must be Blue instead of Grey so it seems like Blue band is still on Top of grey band.
- What I have tried:-

  - One way to do is draw all grey path then draw all blue path . But shape I am trying to plot have multiple grey and blue overlaps which need to plot in an order for path animation so I cant do like this .
  - I tried using `PorterDuffXfermode`on Grey paths but none of the PorterDuffXfermode seems to work

    for (Pair pathColor
                : pathColorList) {

    ```
        if (pathColor.second == Color.GRAY) {

            if (shader == null) {
                shader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, getWidth(),
                        Color.DKGRAY, Color.LTGRAY, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);
                paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC));
                paint.setColor(pathColor.second);

            }
            paint.setShader(shader);

        } else {
            paint.setShader(null);
            paint.setColor(pathColor.second);
            paint.setXfermode(null);
        }

        canvas.drawPath(pathColor.first, paint);
    }
    ```

I am unable to figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: first draw grey stuff, followed by blue stuff, there is no need to use Xfermodes

Comment: Yes this was the first thing I tried and I also mentioned it in question. I also need path draw animation which cant be done if I draw half of view first then other half.

Comment: what `path draw animation` do you mean?

Comment: http://www.curious-creature.com/2013/12/21/android-recipe-4-path-tracing/

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

1.- Put you colors in an array ordered by your color preferences.

```
public static final int COLORS[]={Color.BLUE,Color.RED,Color.YELLOW, Color.MAGENTA,Color.GREEN,Color.CYAN};
```

2.- The object **Path** have a int variable keeping the color **Path**.

3.- Before paint you have a List containg the **Path** objects

4.- Before paint order this **Path** list by color attribute and with the color preferences criteria described in 1

Good luck!!!!